# What is the DirectShow filter can connect to H.264(raw format) output pin?

Tags: directshow, h.264

I am writing a File Source filter which has an Video output PIN, the output pin type is H.264 raw format:

```
HRESULT CVideoOutPin::GetMediaType(CMediaType *pMediaType)
{
    CAutoLock lock(m_pFilter->pStateLock());

    ZeroMemory(pMediaType, sizeof(CMediaType));


    pMediaType->InitMediaType();
    // {7807c3af-524f-11ce-9f53-0020af0ba770}
    pMediaType->SetSubtype(&MEDIASUBTYPE_h264raw);

    unsigned int * pSize = (unsigned int *) pMediaType->ReallocFormatBuffer(sizeof(unsigned int) * 2);
    pSize[0] = m_pFlvFile->GetWidth();
    pSize[1] = m_pFlvFile->GetHeight();

    pMediaType->SetFormat((BYTE *)pSize, sizeof(unsigned int) * 2);

    //*pMediaType = m_oVideoMediaType;

    return S_OK;
}
```

I tried several decompress filter in GraphEdit.exe, and none of them can connect to my output pin.

Is there any DirectShow Filter I can use to complete the graph?

Comment: There is little mystery about well-formed H.264 media types. Build a graph with one of the H.264 files, such as `.AVI` or `.MP4` with GraphEdit and inspect media types there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MEDIASUBTYPE_h264raw` doesn't look like a standard media subtype. You should use `MEDIASUBTYPE_AVC1` (no start codes) or `MEDIASUBTYPE_H264` (with start codes) instead; see [H.264 Media Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you use either of those subtypes, a suitable H.264 decoder should be able to connect to your output pin. Windows 7 comes with such an H.264 decoder, and third-party decoders should supply an appropriate input filter.

Comment: Thanks, MEDIASUBTYPE_AVC1, so I just need send each NALU as an individual sample?  how about PPS & SPS? should I send them together? together with an IFrame NALU?

Comment: Provide PPS and SPS as part of the format (MPEG2VIDEOINFO), in the sequence header data. Again, see the link I posted for more details. You can send each NALU as an individual sample, or put more than one NALU in a media sample. But you cannot let media samples contain partial NALUs under AVC1 subtype.

Comment: Thanks, I always remember to accept the answer provided by friendly guy like you :)